# Form validation in javascript with return false

Tags: javascript, forms

During form validation in javascript why do we return false after every if statement that checks for empty input strings?

```
if (document.myForm.Name.value == "") {
    alert("Please provide your name!");
    document.myForm.Name.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the return false stops the form from submitting. Try changing it to true and it will execute the form submission sending a blank or empty value. When a return command is executed the function has done its part and returns the control to the stack of commands, which can be any other function calls.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the form of reloading the page or navigating to the page that is filled in into the action attribute of the form.